# How to plot sine wave?

Tags: c++11, fft, waveform

I am new to C++ programming and I would like to plot a sine/cosine/square wave but I cannot find any resources to help me with it.

My goal is to produce any wave, and then perform a fourier transform of that wave and produce the resultant wave.

Comment: You can use OpenGL for the drawing, and an FFT package such as KissFFT for the FFT part.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. Just make sure you run it on an IDE that has `graphics.h`. In many new IDEs `graphics.h` doesn't come by default and you have to add it first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

initwindow(800,600);
int x,y;
line(0,500,getmaxx(),500); //to draw co-ordinate axes
line(500,0,500,getmaxy());

float pi = 3.14;
for(int i = -360; i < 360 ; i++){
    x = (int)500+i;
    y = (int)500 - sin(i*pi/100)*25;
    putpixel(x,y,WHITE); //to plot points on the graph
}
getch(); //to see the resultant graph
closegraph();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using Visual Studios. I'll see if I can find a way to get a graphics.h file